# Why can't I login to minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am using my email address rather than profile name but it isn't working...I thought that maybe I was using the wrong password, so I changed it, but it still isn't working.

I don't know why.

My internet connection is great.

If there is anything I am doing wrong please let me know. I have had my account for less than a month and I am very irritated.

Is it possible there is an error on Mojang's side??

Comment: Has anything changed with your setup since you last logged in successfully?

Comment: Whats it saying when you fail to log on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got some sort of Firewall or Antivirus Software? If so, disable it and try logging in. If that doesn't work, [go to this website and see if the Mojang Servers are down](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/%E2%80%8E). If it's not, it's your Minecraft.

How about re-installing your cilent if the above doesn't work?

If you still have login issues, [contact Mojang](http://mojang.com).

Comment: Thank you tho I have tried that. I have checked my firewall and I dont have a Antivirus thing, and uninstalled then re-installed Java. If it isn't better in a week I am contacting Mojang. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep on log in into the server over and over until you can get in.

Comment: Thank you I have tried that tho and have been since November 24th...